# Can you detect if your web page is running inside your Windows Mobile native App?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, user-agent

How can you check that a web page is being served under a native app on Windows phone?

You cant use custom user agents, so to date we have done the following...

Check the user agent for `Windows Phone`, check it for `WebBrowser` which indicates its served from the WebBrowser windows control, and then try to call a method in our native app to guarantee we are in our app.

However, the latest browser updates to windows have removed `WebBrowser` from the user agent.

This means there would be delay when viewing the page on Mobile IE, as we would have to try to talk to our native app to see if it's there or not, and wait for a timeout to assume its not there.

So..

1) Is there anyway now to set custom user agents in windows Mobile - everything we have tried to date has failed.

2) Is there another way we can indicate to the page that its running in our app?  Inject some JS at the start  some how?

3) Any other way to somehow tell the web page what its running in?  Cookies, local storage?

We need to know where its running before it has finished loading, so JS scripts can tell where they are running as they load up.

m

Comment: Let me ask: how do you _talk_ with your native app? If you're using an embedded browser control then you may use [window.external](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246(v=vs.85).aspx) object. If there is the function you're looking for (the one you added from code in your native app) then you're inside your web browser control. If you don't care about _who_ hosts your page then you may simply check for a _random_ function.

Comment: Yes we use window.external.  The issues is that is Async, so to check we are NOT in our app, we have to call a method in our app via window.external and wait for a time out..   Im trying to avoid the timeout....

Comment: Then you may add a _dummy_ function you call only to test if you're inside your app or not. window.external mechanism is, by itself, synchronous so you can catch the exception immediately (no need to wait any timeout).

Comment: Thats what we used to do, until windows 8.1, where window.external became Async.  So now we do it Async, hence the wait for a response...

Comment: Does it? I didn't know and still can't find any reference, can you please link msdn page?